# Expression blend for WPF 4 release date

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I understand that Visual Studio 2010 is being released 12 April, but does anyone know when Expression Blend for .NET and WPF 4 is being released?  I have the beta, but it is pretty buggy and it crashes a lot.

I have not had much luck searching for the release date, so any help would put my mind at ease.

Cory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release version of Expression Blend 4 was released on June 7, 2010 as part of Expression Studio 4.

Answer (score 2):

Blend 4 RC available for download. Looks like from a few days ago (14 APR 2010)

Comment: Great!  If their schedule is anything similar to other products, then the RTM should be between 2 and 6 months.  Thanks!

Comment: I hope not, the trial is for 60 days